# How is the notation $\{ \, . \} $ read in Mathematics

Tags: notation, terminology

I come across these notations often, I was wondering, how do you read them?

For instance, $\left\{ x \right\}$ where $\left\{ \, . \right\}$ denotes the fractional part function.

So. how do I read $\left\{ \, . \right\}$?

Another example,

$ y = e^{2x+1} $ So the **argument of** $ e^{(  .  )} $ is $2x + 1$ again, how do I read the $( \, . )$

Thanks

Comment: This isn’t definitive, but for your second example, I might say “the argument of the exponential function is two ex plus one.”

Comment: Well, how would you read $\{x\}$ in the first place?

Comment: @Crosby It's read as fractional part of $x$

Comment: @William, so your sentence would be, "the fractional part of $x$, where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part of $\cdot$" That seems a bit redundant to me.

Comment: My interpretation of the dot (which is not necessarily universal) is similar to David's, that it is intended to define or clarify an operator notation  that might otherwise not be familiar to the reader.  For example the notation vec(.) allows one to talk about the column vectorization operator for a matrix.

Comment: @JohnPolcari Yes I agree, it is intended to define an operator. But how do you read it?

Comment: @William I think it's rather meaningless to say this out loud; as mentioned, it's just a device to familiarize a *reader* with notation. If you insist, however, I would just say something like "$\{x\}$ where the brackets denote the fractional part of $x$." This is more relevant if you are explaining something you wrote on (say) a chalkboard, as then one does not necessarily have to pronounce $\{x\}$ before one has given its meaning.

Comment: Not sure what you mean be "reading" it.  I always use it to simply show the notation of the operator, with subsequent words to explain what that notation means.

Comment: We write things all the time that sound strange when read aloud.  Writing: "Consider $\Gamma(5)$, where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function."  Reading: "Consider gamma of $5$, where gamma is the gamma function."

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues. In your first example, the braces are one kind of grouping symbol and do not usually represent a mathematical object itself. Counterexamples are usually abuse of notation. For example, $\, (n,m) \,$ is often used to denote the greatest common divisor of $\,n\,$ and $\,m.\,$ However it is standard to use $\, \{n,m\} \,$ to denote the set with elements $\,n\,$ and $\,m.\,$ My preference would be to use "For instance, x wrapped in braces where braces denote the fractional part function." There are other ways to say the same thing.

In your second example, there is a use of positioning to represent a hidden and unnamed function. In this case, the power function. For historical reasons the logarithm function $\, \log_b(x) \,$ is explictly named while the inverse function $\, \textrm{pow}_b(x) := b^x \,$ is not. Also, for historical reasons the function $\, \exp(x) = e^x \,$ is singled out. My preference would be to simply use "y equals e raised to the power 2x plus 1." This seems clear and simple to me, but there are other ways to say the same thing.

Comment: This particular "power" function actually does have a name: the exponential function, sometimes denoted $\exp(\cdot).$